# Calling Stored Procedure using ADODB in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, adodb-php

I couldn't find a proper documentation on how to call a stored procedure using ADODB in PHP. Can someone help please?

This is what I have now and I feel it's a dirty approach (or not?):

```
$stmt = "CALL LocFillData('foo', 'bar', @nullcount, @totalcount)";
$rsstmt = "SELECT @nullcount, @totalcount";
$rs = $db->Execute($stmt);
$rsstmt = $db->Execute($rsstmt);
var_dump($rsstmt);
```

Instead of hardcoding the `CALL` statement, is there any way to code it for multi-database standard?

### EDIT 01:

I tried this code as suggested in the [ADODB Manual](http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-oracle.htm):

```
$dbname = DB_DATABASE;
$tbname = TABLE_CONTACT_LOCATIONS;

$stmt = $db->PrepareSP("BEGIN; adodb.LocFillData(:dbname, :tbname, :nullcount, :totalcount); END;");
$db->InParameter($stmt,$dbname,'dbname');
$db->InParameter($stmt,$tbname,'tbname');
$db->OutParameter($stmt,$nullcount,'nullcount');
$db->OutParameter($stmt,$totalcount,'totalcount');
$ok = $db->Execute($stmt) or die($db->ErrorMsg());

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($ok);
echo "</pre>";
```

But the result was:

```
object(ADORecordSet_empty)#15 (6) {
  ["dataProvider"]=>
  string(5) "empty"
  ["databaseType"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["EOF"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["_numOfRows"]=>
  int(0)
  ["fields"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["connection"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

What could be the problem? The documentation was for Oracle and I am using MySQL. But I believe ADODB methods are same for all DBs.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: really? I found several articles on my first try: http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-oracle.htm

Comment: I tried that before and without any success I posted the question here.

Comment: Please find the output I received. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I found the answer myself. There is no clean way to do that in ADODB for MySQL. The `PrepareSP()` method can be used, but not the `InParameter` or the `OutParameter` methods.

The ADODB documentation says:

> InParameter() is a wrapper function
>   that calls Parameter() with
>   $isOutput=false. The advantage of this
>   function is that it is
>   self-documenting, because the
>   $isOutput parameter is no longer
>   needed. **Only for mssql and oci8
>   currently.**
>
> OutParameter() is a wrapper function
>   that calls Parameter() with
>   $isOutput=true. The advantage of this
>   function is that it is
>   self-documenting, because the
>   $isOutput parameter is no longer
>   needed. **Only for mssql and oci8
>   currently.**

Comment: Is there no better solution?

Answer (score 1):

I have done this through by Adodb library check out this..
$addProduct = $obj->ExecuteQuery("Begin;DECLARE @ProductCode as varchar (100) ;EXEC CREATEPRODUCT'$pname', '$price', @ProductCode OUTPUT, '$merchantId';select @ProductCode;End;");

for complete explanation you can check out this
http://developer99.blogspot.com/2011/07/calling-ms-sql-sp-from-php.html

Answer (score 0):

this option to also use it:

- `$rs = $db->Execute($stmt);`
- `$rsstmt = $db->Execute($rsstmt);`

seems appropriate, because `PrepareSP ()` is used adodb and oracle.
I have not had any luck trying the same adodb library and mysql. as you did your Nirmal.