# How I call a Stored Procedure in AdoDB & MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, adodb

> **MySQL Procedure**

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP procedure `verifica_nf` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `verifica_nf` (IN _id_servidor_val BIGINT, IN _nr_periodo_val INT)

BEGIN

DECLARE nota INT;
DECLARE falta INT;

-- Declare variables used just for cursor and loop control
DECLARE no_more_rows BOOLEAN;
DECLARE loop_cntr INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE num_rows INT DEFAULT 0;

-- CURSOR--

DECLARE NF_CUR CURSOR FOR 
    -- //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// --
    -- // VERIFICA SE E PERIODO ATIVO                                // --
    -- //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// --
    SELECT 
    DISTINCT 
    a.nr_notafinal,
    cr.nr_faltas
    FROM 
    pmc_servidor s
    INNER JOIN pat_avaliacao a ON s.id_servidor  = a.id_servidor       
    INNER JOIN pat_avaliacaoetapa ae ON a.id_avaliacao = ae.id_avaliacao  
    INNER JOIN pat_cronograma cr ON s.id_servidor = cr.id_servidor        
    AND cr.nr_periodo = a.nr_periodo
    WHERE 
    s.id_servidor = _id_servidor_val  AND 
    a.nr_periodo  = _nr_periodo_val;

-- Declare 'handlers' for exceptions
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET no_more_rows = TRUE;

OPEN NF_CUR;

the_loop: LOOP

    FETCH  NF_CUR INTO nota,  falta;

    IF no_more_rows THEN 
        LEAVE the_loop;
    END IF;

SELECT nota, falta;

  END LOOP the_loop;

END;

$$
```

> **PHP Script**

```
<?php
require_once("inc/con.php");

$db = ADONewConnection('mysqli');
$db->debug=1;
$db->PConnect("localhost","root","xxxxx","database");

$id = '1197614';
$period = 1;

$stmt = "CALL verifica_nf('$id','$periodo')";

$rs = $db->Execute($stmt);

echo $rs;
?>
```

---

The PHP script returns **nota** and **falta** value of database variables, but returns too the name of
database variables. Like this:

**(mysqli): CALL verifica_nf('1197614','1')

nota,falta 10000,1**

How can I get the values in a PHP variable?

Comment: fire MySQL Query as you normally do with query as "Call verifica_nf(...)"

Comment: How I put the parameters? Could you me show how I do with AdoDB?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308790/calling-stored-procedure-using-adodb-in-php

Comment: Thanks, but in the last lines of the post that you sent, you see that the user didn't get working with MySQL and AdoDB.